# SwiftUI: AVAudioPlayer does not stop

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an AVAudioPlayer with some key data in an Observable Object:

```
class Player: ObservableObject {
    var data: Data?
    var player: AVAudioPlayer?
    
    init() {}
    
    func play(audioData: Data) {
        self.stop()
        
        // Set the data for the player
        self.data = audioData
        
        do {
            self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(data: audioData)
        } catch {
            debugPrint("error")
        }
        
        // Play with the audio if it exists
        player?.prepareToPlay()
        player?.play()
    }
    
    func pause() {
        player?.pause()
    }
    
    func stop() {
        player?.stop()
        player?.currentTime = 0
    }
}
```

The `stop()` function is not called `player?.stop`, because for an unknown reason, the `AVAudioPlayer` is nil (even though it's playing the audio).

In the view, when I play it, I want to `mutate` the `struct` containing the data. The view looks like this:

```
struct MainView: View {
  @ObservedObject var player = Player()
  var body: some View { 
    ForEach(audioDataList) { audioData in 
      SubView(audioData: audioData).environmentObject(player)
    }
  }
} 

struct SubView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var player: Player
  var audioData: AudioData
  var body: some View {
    Text("Play or stop")
      .onTapGesture {
        player.play()
        audioData.mutateAudioDataStruct()
      }
  } 
}
```

Why does the audio not stop playing when I'm calling `player.play()`? I have the `stop()` function in there and the AVAudioPlayer is clearly not nil if it's playing audio.

Comment: You've left out some important code. Your `Player` class won't compile right now because of syntax errors, which makes me wonder if there are some other things left out as well. You say `stop` doesn't get called, but you don't show where you're trying to call it from. You have `ForEach(audioDataList)`, but don't show what `audioDataList` is. It's also not clear what `mutateAudioDataStruct()` is trying to do, but you don't show the type or the code, so it's hard to say. In general, you can't call a mutating function on a struct in a `View` like this unless it's a `@State` variable.

Comment: @jnpdx `stop` does get called, if you look at the `player.play()` function, which is why I wrote "Why does the audio not stop playing when I'm calling `player.play()`?". Furthermore, `audioDataList` passes `audioData: AudioData` as the `SubView` demonstrates. Lastly,  the syntax error is minor and irrelevant to the question. I'll make an edit to prepend `var`.

Comment: Your `play` method has this signature `play(audioData: Data)`, but you're calling it just as `play()`, which wouldn't compile... Is there something left out? Or are you perhaps calling `.play()` on something else? The reason I mentioned the syntax error is because often in questions it is a symptom of something else getting left out. Clearly, there's something going on here (as you pointed out, `player` shouldn't be nil`), so it's important to try to get the details right when diagnosing.

Comment: @jnpdx I think the root issue is actually because of the `mutating func` I'm calling. I've removed that piece and it works just fine. I'm not quite sure how I could cast `AudioData` into conforming to a `Binding` type like your initial comment suggests.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can always declare your own `Binding` -- you don't have to use `@Binding`, for example.

Comment: I think I'm going to do that. If you post an answer here, I'll mark it as correct. Thank you for the help! :-)

Comment: Normally, I'd be happy to post an answer. In this case, though, I'm not exactly sure what it would say... It might be a good candidate to just remove the question.

Comment: @jnpdx Just say the error is because I’m calling a mutating function on a struct within a view, when I should be using an State variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mutate a `struct` owned by a SwiftUI `View`, it should be be a `@State` variable -- trying to mutate non-`@State` variables will at-best not compile (the compiler should tell you that you `Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable`) and, at worst, (if you've somehow found a way around that compiler error), cause unexpected consequences.

*Future readers, see the comments on the original question for a more detailed explanation of how this conclusion was reached*